# For loop output to csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I have been struggling to print output from for loops to CSV files. I tried to replicate a few solutions but was not able to efficiently print the following code accurately in CSV files:

```
for n in cols:
    print("\t", n, end =" ")
print()
cost = 0

for g in sorted(costs):
    print(g, "\t", end ='')
    for n in cols:
        y = res[g][n]
        if y != 0:
            print (y, end =' ')
            export_df = y
        cost += y * costs[g][n]
        print ('\t', end = '')
    print()
```

Any suggestions would really help me to find direction.

Comment: What is `costs`, `res`? You should update your question and put there sample input and expected output.

Comment: Use the `csv` module to read and write CSV files.

Comment: You assign `export_df`, but never use it. Why is that? The name suggests that it shoul dbe a dataframe, but it's just a single number.